# $a, 1, b$ are three consecutive terms of an arithmetic series, find $a, b$ and $S$ of the infinite geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

$a, 1, b$ are three consecutive terms of an arithmetic series, and $b, a$ and $\frac{8}{3}$ are the first three terms of an infinite geometric series that has a sum of $S$. find $a, b$ and $S$.

How do I solve this?

Comment: `How do I start?` Use that $\,b=2-a\,$ for example.

Comment: What would be the next step @dxiv

Comment: Use that $\,2-a, a, \frac{8}{3}\,$ are in geometric progression. You could write that as $\,(2-a)\cdot \frac{8}{3} = a^2\,$. Solve the quadratic to find $a$, then find $b$, then find $S$.

Comment: If $x,y,z$ are in arithmetic progression, then $x+z=2y$. If $x,y,z$ are in geometric progression, then $xz=y^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by $a, 1, b$ are three consecutive terms of an arithmetic series we can know that:$$a+b=2$$
by $b, a$ and $\frac{8}{3}$ are the first three terms of an infinite geometric series we can know that:$$\frac{8}{3}b=a^2$$
so we got such an equation set:$$\begin{cases}a+b=2\\\frac{8}{3}b=a^2\\\end{cases}$$
the solution of above equation set is:$\begin{cases}a_1=\frac43\\b_1=\frac23\end{cases}$ or $\begin{cases}a_2=-4\\b_2=6\end{cases}$

### The first case

the geometric ratio of this geometric sequence $q_1=2$ and $S$ is infinite in this case

### The second case

the geometric ratio of this geometric sequence $q_2=-\frac23$ and $S=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{b_2(1-q_2^n)}{1-q_2}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{6(1-({-\frac23})^n)}{1-(-\frac23)}=\frac{18}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

Since A, 1 and b are in arithmetic progression, so :

$ 1-a = b-1 $,  or 
$a+b = 2 $

Now, since b,a and $ \frac{8}{3} $ are in geometric progression, so:
$$a^2 = \frac{8b}{3}$$
$$(2-b)^2 = \frac{8b}{3} $$ 
$$ 3b^2 - 20b + 12 = 0 $$
$$ b = \frac {20 ^+_- \sqrt{(20^2 - 4.3.12)}} {2.3}  $$
$$ b = \frac {20 ^+_- \sqrt{256}} { 6} $$
$$ b = \frac {20 ^+_- 16} {6} $$

$ b = 6 $ or $\frac{2}{3} $

$a = 2 - b$
 $ = -4 $ or $ \frac{4}{3} $

There is one important thing to note here. Out of the two sets of values, one set of a and b does not satisfy the arithmetic progression. So you can discard that set of values, hence you have only one unique solution each for a and b.

Now, use the formula for sum of infinite series: $S = \frac{a}{(1-r)}$ , where r = common ratio $= \frac{a}{b} $. I hope you can find that.